# How to add year/months/day to a current date using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS and now i would like to how to add the year from current date.

Let's say i can get the user DOB and i want to add the year+1.

I have tried by using,

```
   $scope.userdob = $rootScope.user.dob;
   $scope.userdob.add(1,'years');
```

but it's not working.

Can anyone help me to know about this logic with example ?

TIA..,

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.setDate()` function to increment the days.
I created an angular example here http://codepen.io/heshamelghandour/pen/WwodMP

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$rootScope.user.dob` is an instance of `moment` from the `moment.js` library. I think your main problem is angular's change detection cannot detect when you mutate this instance. Because the instance remains the same but the internal underlying date value does change. Thus I'd suggest:

```
$scope.userdob = $rootScope.user.dob.clone().add(1,'years').valueOf();
```

That way angular will get a regular JavaScript Date object instead of a moment instance and it's change detection will work correctly.

FYI to accomplish the same with a standard javascript Date instance you can do:

```
var userdob = new Date();
userdob.setYear(userdob.getFullYear() + 1)
```

To advance the year by 1.

Comment: What's the alternate way to do using angularJS ?

Comment: There's no special angularjs code needed here. This is a basic javascript data type. Just like there's no "angularjs way" to divide a number by 2, you don't need any special angularjs code to increment a date. Just change the `$scope.userdob` date value and angular will automatically detect the change and update the views with the new value.

Comment: Now, i have written the code like this but i am getting error like TypeError: userdob.getFullYear is not a function. var userdob = $rootScope.user.dob;     alert(userdob);      userdob.setYear(userdob.getFullYear() +1);       $scope.event.when = userdob;

Comment: OK, please see my edit. I have a new theory as to what the root cause problem is and the above change should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.setDate()` function to increment the days and instead of +1 day and add +365 days it will give you date after 1 year.